# How to write text from file to an 2 dimensional array

Tags: bash, text-files

I have a text file like this (separated by space-key):

```
    10 18 12 14 1
    11 45 11 34 2
```

I want it to to look like this:

```
    1,1,10
    2,1,18
    3,1,12
    4,1,14
    5,1,1
    1,2,11
    2,2,45
    3,2,11
    4,2,34
    5,2,2
```

In the new output first column is the column in the file and second one is the row. The third is value ... Do you have idea how to do it ?

Answer (score -1):

Bash does not support multi-dimensional arrays. It only supports one-dimensional arrays.

You can use `awk` to create a `col, row, val` stream:

```
cat yourfile.txt | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){print i ", " NR ", " $i}}'
```